# How can I connect two edge loops with different numbers of vertices?

Tags: modeling, vertices

[image: this is the object i want to connect]

I can't use the <kbd>F</kbd> function because the number of vertices in each circle is not same. 
The big one has 48 and the small one has 32 vertices.

Comment: Found a solution. go to face then fill

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, which will both provide similar result here.

- *Edge > Bridge Edge loops*
- *Face > Fill*, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

As @vklidu pointed out, *Face > Fill* gives different results in many cases, notably  when some faces are flipped.

[image]

Comment: Not a little in some cases :) https://imgur.com/a/20S5THA probably it depends on vertex indices in Bridge case … edit: moving centre part a bit up solved this twist.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that :). Looking into this a bit more, it seems Face > Fill also works better for connecting flipped faces. I think I'll edit the answer to cover this.